# java8 stream sum multiple

Tags: java, collections, java-8, sum, java-stream

I am curious, how to sum up multiple variables in a java8 stream.

```
Integer wCPU = 0;
Double wnetwork = 0.0;
Double wMem = 0.0;

this.slaContractList.forEach(sla -> {
    wCPU += sla.getNumberOfCPUs();
    wnetwork += sla.getNetworkBandwith();
    wMem += sla.getMemory();
});
```

However, this does not compile as the variable in the lambda expression should be final.

Comment: You want a custom collector, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37187541/java-8-stream-add-elements-to-list-and-sum/37188002#37188002

Comment: What are the downsides of the hack? it seems to have fewer lines of code which is nice.

Comment: You said it... it's a hack. Run it in parallel, it will likely not produce the right output because `+=`, like `++`, [is not an atomic operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25168062/why-is-i-not-atomic).

Comment: What do you think about the latest answer added by @Lukasz that looks pretty neat as well and does not have the downsides of the Hack.

Comment: Solved with mutablePair from commons collections

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming `slaContractList` is a list of `SlaContract` objects, and it has constructor `SlaContract(numberOfCPUs, networkBandwith, memory)` you can:

```
SlaContract sumContract = slaContractList.stream()
    .reduce(new SlaContract(0, 0.0, 0.0), (sla1, sla2) -> {
         return new SlaContract(sla1.getNumberOfCPUs() + sla2.getNumberOfCPUs(), sla1.getworkBandwith() + sla2.getworkBandwith(), sla1.getMemory() + sla2.getMemory());
    });

Double wnetwork = sumContract.getworkBandwith();
Double wMem = sumContract.getMemory();
Integer wCPU = sumContract.getNumberOfCPUs();
```

The same solution, but for simple class:

```
Point sumPoint = pointsList.stream()
    .reduce(new Point(0, 0), (p1, p2) -> {
         return new Point(p1.x + p2.x, p1.y + p2.y);
    });
```

Comment: `reduce` should never modify its input parameter during accumulation. This will break when run in parallel, it should always return a new object containing the accumulation. [See also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23869930/is-the-accumulator-of-reduce-in-java-8-allowed-to-modify-its-arguments). You want to use `collect` here.

Answer (score 7):

Try to use `Stream.reduce` and `Stream.sum`:

```
Double wnetwork = slaContractList.stream()
            .mapToDouble(sla -> sla.getNetworkBandwith())
            .sum();

Double wMem = slaContractList.stream()
            .mapToDouble(sla -> sla.getMemory())
            .sum();

Integer wCPU = slaContractList.stream()
            .mapToInt(sla -> sla.getNumberOfCPUs())
            .sum();
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html

The advantage of using stream is option of use `parallelStream()` instead of `stream()`. In some situations it can be more efficient than simple loop.

Comment: so you would use a map for each attribute? Isn't this slower as a single loop?

Comment: The thing is it is basically a stream of tuples. And I believe it would be quicker if each value in the tuple would be summed up separately, but within a single pass of the loop.

Comment: Well, that's the way you can sum the stream. Compare this solution with others not using streams. Check `parallelStream()` instead of `stream()` as well.

Comment: `long t0 = System.nanoTime();` 
//solution here
`long t1 = System.nanoTime();`
`long millis = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(t1 - t0);`
`System.out.println(String.format("solution took: %d ms", millis));`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, could you please which solution is faster in your situation? (just copy some code from previous comment)

Comment: I am not sure if this would be useful e.g. we are using this code in a round based simulation where the rounds are executed sequentially with a certain delay.

Comment: OK. In first comment you asked if it isn't slower than single loop, so I thought it matters.

Comment: It does not matter right now. I wanted to learn how to approach such a problem. But it might in the future. Thank you very much for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Just to do a sum, i would use the sum operation of streams just like in Łukasz answer, but, for a more general solution for resolving the "final problem" you can use the classes of java.util.concurrent.atomic. It is intented to be used in stream and is thread-safe, so could be used in a parallel stream.

```
AtomicInteger wCPU = new AtomicInteger();
DoubleAccumulator wnetwork = new DoubleAccumulator(Double::sum,0.d);
DoubleAccumulator wMem = new DoubleAccumulator(Double::sum,0.d);

this.slaContractList.forEach(sla -> {
    wCPU.addAndGet(sla.getNumberOfCPUs());
    wnetwork.accumulate(sla.getNetworkBandwith());
    wMem.accumulate(sla.getMemory());
});
```

Now you see that there are 2 kind of implementation: the *Accumulator and the Atomic*, the choice between these 2 is another question:

[java 8 : Are LongAdder and LongAccumulator preferred to AtomicLong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35688862/java-8-are-longadder-and-longaccumulator-preferred-to-atomiclong)

Comment: This seems to be cleaner than creating an additional constructor.

Answer (score 3):

I would do a simple hack like this:

```
    Integer[] wCPU = new Integer[1];
    Double[] wnetwork = new Double[1];
    Double[] wMem = new Double[1];

    this.slaContractList.forEach(sla -> {
        wCPU[0] += sla.getNumberOfCPUs();
        wnetwork[0] += sla.getNetworkBandwith();
        wMem[0] += sla.getMemory();
    });
```

It's optional to have the `final` keyword for both , as in Java 8 they have introduced the *effectively final* concept. It means, you have assigned only once.

Comment: I like your hack ;)

Comment: Sorry for switching. But I think the other answer is nicer / not a hack.

Comment: These are "conceptually" Mutable integer and double, the only problem is that it is not Thread-safe, but it work for simple problem withotu threads.