# Java sum of fields in one object using lambda expressions

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have objects like this:

```
class DailyReport{
LocalDate day;
Long criticalErrors;
Long browserErrors;
Long OtherErrors;
}
```

Now I get list of this objects and want to create summaryobject i.e

```
class Summary{
  LocalDate startDate;
LocalDate endDate;
Long sumOfCritical;
Long sumOfBrowser;
Long sumOfOthers
}
```

I created sth like this:

```
List<DailyReport> dailyReports=repository.findAll();
Summary summary = new Summary(
 dailyReports.get(0).getDay;
 dailyReports.get(dailyReports.size() - 1).getDay;
summary.stream().mapToLong(DailyReport::getCriticalErrors).sum(),
summary.stream().mapToLong(DailyReport::getBrowserErrors).sum(),
summary.stream().mapToLong(DailyReport::getOtherErrors).sum(),
}
```

But for me it looks inefficient - is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Why use Long, not long?

Comment: What looks inefficient to you (apart from the unnecessary boxing/unboxing operations)?

Comment: And please fix the source example. Especially the last part is mixing up , with ; and uses ( ... but then closes with }. Seriously: dont dump stuff on us that doesn't even compile!

Comment: I assume you are talking about the 3 sums when you say "inefficient". Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40567935/java8-stream-sum-multiple)?

Comment: `It looks inefficient` => I think it is not. But it looks very readable, which is fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce a stream by implementing the logic of "adding" a report to a summary object, and the logic of combining two summary objects.

Here's what that looks like:

```
//Adds a report to a summary
BiFunction<Summary, DailyReport, Summary> reportMerger = (summ, rep1) -> {
    Summary summary = new Summary();

    summary.setStartDate(rep1.getDay().isAfter(summ.getStartDate()) ? 
                rep1.getDay() : summ.getStartDate());
    summary.setEndDate(rep1.getDay().isAfter(summ.getEndDate()) ? 
                summ.getEndDate() : rep1.getDay());
    summary.setSumOfCritical(rep1.getCriticalErrors() 
                + summ.getSumOfCritical());
    summary.setSumOfBrowser(rep1.getBrowserErrors() 
                + summ.getSumOfBrowser());
    summary.setSumOfOthers(rep1.getOtherErrors() 
                + summ.getSumOfOthers());

    return summary;
};

//combines 2 summary objects
BinaryOperator<Summary> summaryMerger = (s1, s2) -> {
    Summary summ = new Summary();

    summ.setStartDate(s1.getStartDate().isBefore(s2.getStartDate()) ? 
                s1.getStartDate() : s2.getStartDate());
    summ.setEndDate(s1.getEndDate().isBefore(s2.getEndDate()) ? 
                s2.getEndDate() : s1.getEndDate());

    summ.setSumOfCritical(s1.getSumOfCritical() 
                + s2.getSumOfCritical());
    summ.setSumOfBrowser(s1.getSumOfBrowser() 
                + s2.getSumOfBrowser());
    summ.setSumOfOthers(s1.getSumOfOthers() 
                + s2.getSumOfOthers());

    return summ;
};
```

And then reduce a stream of reports into a single summary

```
Summary summary = dailyReports.stream()
     .reduce(new Summary(), reportMerger, summaryMerger);
```

Note: you need to add null checks for the null fields of `new Summary()` in the comparisons above (to avoid NPEs).

---

An alternative way to collect (thanks to Eugene's comments) that removes the need for new objects:

```
Summary summaryTwo = dailyReports.stream().collect(Collector.of(Summary::new, 
    (summ, rep) -> {
        //add rep to summ
    }, (summary1, summary2) -> {
        //merge summary2 into summary1
        return summary1;
    }));
```

Comment: I *think* you can do the same to a *mutable* reduction, via `Collector.of`

Comment: @Eugene Almost... except for the `startDate` and `endDate` part, which won't have a place when using a `BiConsumer<DailyReport>`

Comment: it looks like you are coding like a *mutable reduction*, but using `reduce`, in each step for `reduce` you must return a new instance

Comment: @Eugene 100%. Edited last function

Comment: and now you get to my first point, you can do the same thing, without the extra objects, if you would use `Collector.of`, right?

Comment: Right. I'm sure I read that too quickly (thought `stream.collect`, not `Collector.of`). Will add

Comment: `stream.collect(Collector.of(...))` since it looks like you might need a finisher (or not, have not looked to close, I admit)

Answer (score 1):

You can loop on dailyReports and calculate values like

```
LocalDate startDate =  dailyReports.get(0).getDay;
LocalDate endDate =  dailyReports.get(dailyReports.size() - 1).getDay;

Long sumOfCritical=0L;
Long sumOfBrowser=0L;
Long sumOfOthers=0L;

dailyReports.stream().foreach(o->{ 
sumOfCritical += o.getCriticalErrors();
sumOfBrowser += o.getBrowserErrors();
sumOfOthers += o.getOtherErrors();
})

Summary summary = new Summary(startDate, endDate,sumOfCritical, sumOfBrowser, sumOfOthers)
```